# Film plots explained badly

Tags: knowledge, movies

> Everybody slept for most of the movie.
>
> An Apple computer discovered some plant and eventually make everyone do exercise.
>
> It’s a Shakespeare adaptation but with cats and monkeys.
>
> 90+ year old government employee convinced a group of friends to betray his country.
>
> Sport athlete got caught by the police and forced to do manual labor, ended up learning humility and got sweet sponsorships.
>
> Man killed a dog then died because a woman brought him home.
>
> Genius with superiority complex abandoned job offers to chase some girl he met in a bar.
>
> Middle age man with unorthodox diet help chasing someone obsessed with skincare products.
>
> A son understood his immigrant father more after he went to Europe and fell in love with a girl.
>
> Two men arrived in Los Angeles seeking a young kid. You’d want to root for the more muscular one.

Comment: 1. *Batman v Superman* ;)

Comment: Hey, so everyone got the correct answer :) Who should I award the solved to?

Comment: For puzzles with multiple pieces like this one, some people award the checkmark to the person who contributed the most correct solutions (and optionally give more weight to harder entries, to help break ties.) It's nice to specify a rule in advance, but not necessary. This reduces the angst in picking which answer to accept.  Of course, sometimes the person with the most contributions makes the decision an easy one by consolidating all the solutions (with credit to their posters) into their own answer, which is also fine. As is a community wiki, if someone is ok forgoing rep.

Comment: It wasn't immediately clear to me that these are all separate films rather than several clues to the same film

Comment: VTC, this belongs to scifi.stackexchange with the [story-identification] tag.

Comment: 1. Solaris (Tarkovsky's 1972 version) ;-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

EDIT: I'll have to do a little extra work in collating all the correct answers to earn my green tick, so here they are:

Everybody slept for most of the movie.

> Inception, where most of the movie happened in dreams, dreamt by the characters who were asleep.

An Apple computer discovered some plant and eventually make everyone do exercise.

> WALL-E - humanity is obese, the earth's environment is shot, the titular robot discovers a plant, and at its conclusion they start restoring the environment and get people off their behinds! Courtesy of Phylyp.

It’s a Shakespeare adaptation but with cats and monkeys.

> The Lion King. It's basically Hamlet with lions. Courtesy of Jaap Scherphuis.

90+ year old government employee convinced a group of friends to betray his country.

> Captain America: Civil War. Captain America, the world's oldest soldier, led the faction of superheroes who were against the Sokovia Accord as mandated by the UN.

Sport athlete got caught by the police and forced to do manual labor, ended up learning humility and got sweet sponsorships.

> Cars. Lightning McQueen is a racer car, gets caught in Radiator Springs and has to repave the road, learns humility in the process. Gets sponsored by Rust-eeze. Courtesy of Thorbjorn Ravn Andersen.

Man killed a dog then died because a woman brought him home.

> I am legend. Will Smith's character has to kill his infected dog, goes mad and is found by a woman. This woman brings him home, without covering their tracks, so they are tracked. Courtesy of Kamil Jurek.

Genius with superiority complex abandoned job offers to chase some girl he met in a bar.

> Good Will Hunting (1997). Will (the protagonist) is a math prodigy with a superiority complex who rejects a lucrative job offer from the NSA and instead drives to California to reconnect with Skylar (a girl he met at a bar). Courtesy of ConjuringFrictionForces.

Middle age man with unorthodox diet help chasing someone obsessed with skincare products.

> Silence of the Lambs: Hannibal Lecter most definitely has an unusual diet, and he helped Clarice Starling arrest the serial killer Buffalo Bill, who was seen putting on a lot of make-up.

A son understood his immigrant father more after he went to Europe and fell in love with a girl.

> Godfather. Michael Corleone goes back to Italy and falls in love with an italian girl. Courtesy of Thorbjorn Ravn Andersen again.

Two men arrived in Los Angeles seeking a young kid. You’d want to root for the more muscular one.

> Terminator 2: Judgment Day, courtesy of user137369. The good robot (titular terminator) as played by the massive Arnold Schwarzenegger, is looking to save said young kid.

Comment: Very nice. If you think my answer is correct, go ahead and incorporate it into yours, you're well on your way to completing it.

Comment: And who can forget: 'It puts the lotion on its skin or else it gets the hose again'.

Comment: I think the girl might be Minnie Driver

Comment: Check my answer for the "genius with a superiority complex" and feel free to take it if you think it fits better.

Comment: "the massive Arnold Schwarzenegger" made me laugh.

Comment: As I've said before - The Lion King is Hamlet with slightly fewer murders and slightly more incest.

Comment: The answers to "Cars" is slightly incorrect - McQueen was sponsored by Rusteeze from the very beginning, but at the end got a deal from Dinoco (which he turned down which makes the puzzle a little bit incorrect, since he was offered the sponsorship but did not get it).

Answer (score 23):

An Apple computer discovered some plant and eventually make everyone do exercise.

> **[WALL-E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WALL-E)** - humanity is obese, the earth's environment is shot, the titular robot discovers a plant, and at its conclusion they start restoring the environment and get people off their behinds!

Comment: Nah, EVE is the Apple Computer. All white chassis with black bits.

Comment: @Malandy Wall-E has the Apple boot chime.  Definitively Apple too.

Answer (score 20):

It’s a Shakespeare adaptation but with cats and monkeys.

> The Lion King. It's basically Hamlet with lions.

Answer (score 16):

Two men arrived in Los Angeles seeking a young kid. You’d want to root for the more muscular one.

> Terminator 2: Judgment Day

Answer (score 15):

Sport athlete got caught by the police and forced to do manual labor, ended up learning humility and got sweet sponsorships.

> Cars.  Lightning McQueen is a racer car, gets caught in Radiator Springs and has to repave the road, learns humility in the process.  Gets sponsored by Rust-eeze.

A son understood his immigrant father more after he went to Europe and fell in love with a girl.

> Godfather.  Michael Corleone goes back to Italy and falls in love with an italian girl.

Answer (score 14):

Genius with superiority complex abandoned job offers to chase some girl he met in a bar.

> Good Will Hunting (1997). Will (the protagonist) is a math prodigy with a superiority complex who rejects a lucrative job offer from the NSA and instead drives to California to reconnect with Skylar (a girl he met at a bar).

Comment: Yes! This was the only one I could solve.

Answer (score 13):

Man killed a dog then died because a woman brought him home.

> I am legend. Will Smith's character has to kill his infected dog, goes mad and is found by a woman. This woman brings him home, without covering their tracks, so they are tracked

Answer (score 3):

Everybody slept for most of the movie.

> The matrix. Everybody lives in a fake dream world, while there bodies are asleep in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody slept for most of the movie.

> Passenger 4998 colonists and 258 crew members were kept 'asleep' (hibernation) the entire movie until they almost reach there destination.

It's open for discussion whether hibernation is a form of sleep though